# Visual Studio2019でMFCアプリを作成するプロジェクトでのプロパティウィンドウの項目の文字列を日本語ではなく英語で表示したい

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio2019でMFCアプリを作成するプロジェクトでのプロパティウィンドウの項目の文字列が日本語になっています。学習書を読みながら作業しているのですが、学習書ではVisual Studio2005を想定して書かれており、プロパティの項目名が英語で表記されています。

いちいち、学習書の英語表記に対応する日本語表記を探すのが面倒なので、プロパティウィンドウの項目名の日本語表記を英語表記にしたいのですがどうすればいいのかわかりません。。

どなたかご存じないでしょうか？
お手数をおかけしますがよろしくお願いいたします。

[image: プロパティウィンドウの画像]

Comment: 一部だけ変えたいとかいう出来そうも無いことに時間を費やすより、学習書自身をVisualStudio2019(や2022)に対応したものに変えるのが一番では？

Comment: 多少面倒ですがプロパティウィンドウの日本語の項目名と、書籍の英語名を照らし合わせながら学習を進めていこうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

正攻法で行くならVisual Studioを英語化することです。スクリーンショットはVisual Studio 2022のものですが、2019でも同じはずです。

Visual Studio InstallerのLanguage packsでEnglishを選択してインストールする
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Visual StudioのオプションのInternational SettingsでEnglishを選択する
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

Visual StudioのオプションのInternational Settingsでいつでも日本語に戻せますが、使っていくうちに言語切り替えが面倒になり、画像のように英語のみをインストールするようになる人もいるそうです。

Comment: 回答コメントありがとうございます。プロパティウィンドウの項目名だけを日本語にしたいです。全部が英語になると英語がほとんど読めない僕にはつらいです。